# Need help on getting ping to run under wine on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, server, wine, games, ping

I need help getting ping to work under wine on Ubuntu 16.04. I am trying to run a Battlefield Bad Company 2 server for testing (I might be doing some development on a mod at some point) and I am unable to get it to a playable state. I can run mase_bc2 and Frost.Game.Main_Win32_Final.exe and even connect to the LAN server in game - but, when loading a map, it does not continue loading and instead the game freezes.

Here is the error that I need to solve to get the server playable: `0049:err:winediag:IcmpCreateFile Failed to use ICMP (network ping), this requires special permissions.`

When I do `wine cmd` and then `ping` I simply get this:
`Z:\home\user> ping google.com`
`0075:fixme:ping:main this command currently just sleeps based on -n parameter`

Here is what I have tried:

`sudo chmod 4755 /bin/ping` to allow wine to access ping. This did not help.

I then tried this:
`sudo setcap cap_net_raw+epi "$(readlink -f "/usr/bin/wine")"`

which results in this error:
`wine: error while loading shared libraries: libwine.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

and then separately after running `sudo setcap -r "$(readlink -f "/usr/bin/wine")"` to remove the shared libraries error, I also ran this:
`sudo setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' "$(readlink -f "/usr/bin/wine-preloader")"`

Both `setcap` commands result in the same shared libraries error.

I'm decent at Linux but it seems this is beyond my level and I need help with this. I have searched thread after thread online and I came up empty. If someone can solve this for me, this may be one of the only sources of fixing this issue (bug??) on the Internet.

I see there is someone else having this issue here: https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=30704 and he even gets the same error as me after using `setcap` however he did not get this issue solved.

UPDATE Sep 7 2018: creating a symlink at `/usr/lib/libwine.so.1` removes the `shared libraries` error, but I am still unable to ping via wine.

UPDATE Sep 8 2018: This seems to be a known bug and is fixed in Wine Development 3.15: https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=43252

Thanks.

Comment: About the `ping` command not working in Wine — the `this command currently just sleeps based on -n parameter` basically says that ping command is not implemented, probably because nobody was needing it. Your problem with ICMP is about pinging through WinAPI, and being a distinct issue. The rest you already figured out. Since you found it's fixed in 3.15, you might want to post an answer about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is Wine has a bug in it that is fixed in Wine versions 3.14 and beyond where a ReplySize under 56 prevents `ping` from working. However - `ping` still requires special permissions set with `setcap` in Wine versions 3.14 and beyond. Thankfully, there is also a workaround in Wine versions 3.14 and beyond where Wine will automatically use the native Linux `ping` if the special permissions are not set with `setcap` which essentially means in Wine versions 3.14 and beyond, `wine ping` will now work out of the box.

Source: https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=43252